# Multiple Begins in a PostgresSQL script

Tags: postgresql

I currently am trying to have a **single** sql script. I could achieve my end result by executing all scripts one after the other, sequentially.

Currently my scripts creates a bunch of tables and stored procedures, all wrapped within a **transaction/Begin and End.**

```
DO $$
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS licenses (
        license_id smallint NOT NULL,
        name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (license_id)
    );
    ..... create lots of tables ....

END$$;
```

Now I'm trying to add to this script a couple stored procedures, it fails because the stored procedure contains **BEGIN** and that doesn't work within an existing transaction.

I could put the sproc underneath the first transaction but the new sproc should only execute when the previous transaction of creating tables have been committed. May I have any suggestions to move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEGIN you are using is not the [SQL command BEGIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html)  but a PL/pgSQL [block structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)

To start a transaction, stick to SQL:

```
begin transaction;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS licenses (
   license_id smallint NOT NULL,
   name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (license_id)
);

..... create lots of tables ....

create procedure foo() 
as 
$body$
begin 
  ...
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;

create table ...;

commit;

begin transaction;
... create other tables and procedures
commit;
```